# Missing Tasks option at SQL Server Object Explorer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

[sql-server missing tasks option image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV9Ol.png)

I want to generate a script for my database. I researched this issue but there is no solution for my problem. I would be very happy if anyone can help me(and yes, I right-clicked on database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that I need to download [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15) first.